# How to break a standard action on a visualforce page?

Tags: javascript, visualforce, commandbutton

In my vf page, there is a save button that of standard vf command button. A JS confirm will popup when someone click this button. Now, if user has chosen cancel, I want to cancel the action of save. So how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to return false in the Javascript and the execution will stop.

Another example (using standard JS confirm popup)

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!doSomething}" onclick="return confirm('Really?');" value="Do an action." />
```